# how to solve timeout error for this code in hackerrank

Tags: c, timeout, compile-time

```
int sweet(int l,int n,int m )
{  
            if(m==0)

                return l;
            if(l>=n)
                return sweet(1,n,m-1);
            else
            return sweet(l+1,n,m-1);
}

int display(int d)
{    
    if(d==0)

      return 0;
      else
{
     int  n,m,s;

        scanf("%d %d %d",&n,&m,&s);

       printf("%d\n",sweet(s-1,n,m));

       return display(d-1);}
}

int main()
{
    int t;

    scanf("%d",&t);

        display(t);
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is and the provided code is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Timeout error appears to be related to the scanf. If you look at the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf), scanf takes input from standard in. If the specific digits are not present in stdin, the program will hang as scanf will continue waiting for what it's looking for to appear.